# Any way to do a reverse XPath query?

Tags: xpath, saxon

If I have a context node, an XPath expression and a node, is there a way to check if my node satisfies the XPath expression in that context.

I have XPath queries that are very expensive and long to run. Here I would simply like to take a potential result node and check if it satisfies the query, i.e. it would be returned as part of the query result set.

I am using Saxon EE 9.3

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please take some time to read through the [faq], and show some code.

Comment: Depends on the query, but my general approach would be to build a much smaller XML document around my candidate node and test the query on it.

Comment: This was actually our first approach and it would possibly work pretty well in most cases, but as you correctly pointed out it "depends" on the query, and this is a generic query processor so we can't assume much if anything about the query.

Answer (score 0):

If your context node is $N, your expression is E, and the node being tested is $T, then the expression `boolean($N/(EXP) intersect $T)` does what you are asking for in the first part of your question. However, it may not meet the requirement implied by the second part of the question, which is that the computation should be faster than evaluating EXP.

If the expression EXP takes the form of an XSLT pattern then the answer is yes, there is a way and it is likely to be faster (though how to achieve this depends on what Saxon APIs you are using). Note that when EXP is a pattern, the question of whether $T matches the pattern does not depend on knowing a context node $N.

Comment: Most cases are XPath expressions. It can be as simple as `./element(inventoryElement, Project)[@name=$name]` or it could be `.//element(*, ReferenceKey)` or some more complex case navigating up and down the various axes (guess it's the plural of axis).
If the above will be faster for standard child axis cases that is fantastic as this covers 95% of the use cases. Obviously a double slash query especially might navigate the full tree, while taking a node $T and showing that it is indeed "a child" of $N as per expression E then this wouldn't involve parsing the whole tree.